# Express.js jade template layout not working

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I created login form using Node, express and jade template. But my login page not use default layout. Here is my site structure:

[image]

My layout.jade:

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body 
    #header
      h1=title
  != body
```

My route.js:

```
var routes = function(app) {
  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    return res.render(__dirname+"/views/login", {
      title: 'Giriş',
      stylesheet: 'login'
    });
  });
};

module.exports = routes;
```

My login.jade:

```
form(action= '/sessions', method='post')
  label
    | Kullanıcı Adı:
    input(type='text', name='user')
  label
    | Şifre:
    input(type='password', name='password')
  input(type='submit', name='Giriş')
```

And my server.js(app.js):

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

//Routes
require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app)

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

When I try http://www.mylocalhost:3000/login it is working getting no exception but not using my layout.jade. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.
Added this code to login.jade

```
extends ../../../views/layout
block login
```

And this code to layout.jade

```
block login
```